# Is the contraction of How'd ( did or would ) (?)

Tags: grammar, meaning, slang

I’d like to know if the “'d” in “ How'd” is the world “did” or “would”

Comment: [As the dictionary says](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/how%27d), it could be either one: "used as a contraction of *how would* or *how did*"

Comment: Hello Nicolás, since it could be either you'll need to provide more context.  Please edit your question.

Comment: I haven't heard it used as "would".  Sounds very strange, though I get there is nothing technically wrong with it.

Comment: @mjjf "How'd you have done it?"

Comment: @gotube As I said, I know it's not technically wrong, but it sounds strange.

Answer (score 1):

Either one, depending on context. Both "how did" and "how would" contract to "how'd".

"How'd you do that?" - How did you do that?

"How'd you feel if I left?" - How would you feel if I left?